# Elixir error handling pipe options

Tags: error-handling, elixir

The following code is an invalid changeset which errors, however it took me a long time to find the cause because the error message was not originally being matched and logged.

I added a case statement to the end of the pipe, is this the best way to pickup errors in pipes?

```
    User.changeset(%User{}, %{username: "username_is_test", password: "test", password_confirmation: "test", email: "test@test.com"})
    |> Repo.insert
    |> case  do
        {:ok, result} -> IO.puts("result")
        {:error, error} -> IO.inspect error
    end
```

Comment: Not the most beautiful one but it's good enough, also note that an invalid changeset will be assigned to the `error` variable so it's not a really good naming there.

Answer (score 2):

Pipelines and error tuples don't work very well together. You can handle an error at the end of a pipeline with a `case` as you have, but it only works at the last stage.

For operations returning error tuples, I prefer to use `with`/`else` syntax:

```
with changeset <- User.changeset(%User{}, %{username: "username_is_test", password: "test", password_confirmation: "test", email: "test@test.com"})
     {:ok, result} <- Repo.insert(changeset) do
  IO.puts("result")
else
  {:error, error} -> IO.inspect error
end
```

You can add as many failable operations as required in the `with` block, and handle all the error cases with pattern matching in the `else` block.

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options. If you don't want to explicitly handle the error conditions, you should use `Repo.insert!` instead. At least this will raise an exception if the changeset is not valid.

Otherwise, you should be using a case handle handling the `{:error, changeset}` by checking the `changeset.action` in your template.

In more complicated pipelines that can error part way through, I've started using the `with` special form.

```
with result when not is_nil(result) <- fun1, 
     {:ok, result} <- fun2(result), 
     {:ok, result} <- fun3(result) do
  success_handling(result)
else
  nil -> # handle first failure
  {:error, error} -> # handle other errors
  _ -> # catch all failure
end
```